# Modular Arithmetic addition and subtraction using Crypto++

Tags: c++, crypto++, modular-arithmetic

I am very new to this, but I am trying to add two Integers in modular format using Crypto++ Library.

My program is very simple,

```
AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
Integer r0, m;

m = Integer( prng, 64);
r0 = Integer( prng, 64);

cout << "m: " << std::hex << m << endl;
cout << "r0:" << std::hex << r0 << endl;

Integer n1(r0 + m);
```

But this simply didn't work. It complied fine, but it crashed when I was trying to run it.

Could anyone give a sample code for addition/subtraction using Crypto++ please

Comment: *"Could anyone give a sample code for addition/subtraction using Crypto++ ..."* - have you looked at [Integer](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Integer) on the Crypto++ wiki? The wiki has lots of examples and sample code.

Comment: I just looked at it and it only gives examples of the Integer initialization, but not the addition/subtraction of two Integers

Comment: I've been working on this for the last 24 hours, and as I mentioned an addition like r0+m did not work for me. So that is why I was looking for an example for using the Add function in  ModularArithmetic in modarith.h

Comment: This is what I did,CryptoPP::Integer r0, m, sum; 
m= CryptoPP::Integer( prng, 64);

r0= CryptoPP::Integer( prng, 64); 
sum = r0 +m;
It complied, but crashed when it ran

Comment: wait, the page you referenced is being updated.... I am trying something else now

Comment: *"... the page you referenced is being updated..."* - yes, I'm updating it as we we speak. *"...It complied, but crashed when it ran...'* - that's a different problem, and it lacks detail, so I'm guessing you stated it for completeness. I'm addressing the question *"Could anyone give a sample code for addition/subtraction using Crypto++"*.

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much for your help.... I just tried a new program similar to what you have in the page, and it works fine. There must have been something else wrong in my old program.

Comment: Thank you also for updating the page. I spent all day yesterday searching for a simple examples on addition and I couldn't find it. I found RSA, DH...etc, but nothing simple. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks again, I must go to my lab now, but how do I close this question?

Comment: *"How do I close this question..."* - Lower left-hand corner of the question, then select "Close → Off-Topic → No longer reproducible". But I recommend you leave it open because of the unexpected results from [`ModularArithmetic` class](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_modular_arithmetic.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Modular Arithmetic (addition/subtraction) using Crypto++

We have closed some of the missing documentation gaps based on this question, so I won't address the sample code. The improved docs are available at [Integer Class Reference](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_integer.html) and [Integer on the Crypto++ wiki](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Integer).

However, there may be a bug or (at least) unexpected results from using the [ModularArithmetic class](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_modular_arithmetic.html). The class describes itself as *"Ring of congruence classes modulo n"*. Mathematically, a Ring is a group with closure and two well defined operations.

The disconnect is, which two operations are the ones included with `ModularArithmetic<Integer>`. Based on some sample code, it looks like its `Multiply` and `Exponentiate`, which is mostly expected (though it could have been `Add` and `Multiply`).

I don't think the mathematical definition of Ring gives `ModularArithmetic` a license to produce unexpected results. However, `ModularArithmetic` is kind of unique, and it may be accumulating intermediate results that one must then reduce using `Multiply` and `Exponentiate`. (It does accumulate results to speed up operations).

The open question for me is, what do we do... I'm trying to solicit some feedback at the moment on the issue.

---

Here's the test program:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Integer m("4294967295"), n("0x1000000000000000000000000000000"), j;
  j = 1999;

  ModularArithmetic ma(j);

  cout << "n+m mod j: " << ma.Add(n, m) << endl;
  cout << "  cross-check: " << (n+m) % j << endl;
  cout << "n-m mod j: " << ma.Subtract(n, m) << endl;
  cout << "  cross-check: " << (n-m) % j << endl;
  cout << "n*m mod j: " << ma.Multiply(n, m) << endl;
  cout << "  cross-check: " << (n*m) % j << endl;
  cout << "n/m mod j: " << ma.Divide(n, m) << endl;
  cout << "  cross-check: " << (n/m) % j << endl;
  cout << "n%m mod j: " << ma.Reduce(n, m) << endl;
  cout << "  cross-check: " << (n%m) % j << endl;
  cout << "n^m mod j: " << ma.Exponentiate(n, m) << endl;
  cout << "  cross-check: " << a_exp_b_mod_c(n,m,j) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Here are the results:

```
$ ./test.exe 
n+m mod j: 1329227995784915872903807064575309872.
  cross-check: 1755.
n-m mod j: 1329227995784915872903807055985377281.
  cross-check: 50.
n*m mod j: 266.
  cross-check: 266.
n/m mod j: 599.
  cross-check: 1997.
n%m mod j: 1329227995784915872903807055985377281.
  cross-check: 1608.
n^m mod j: 1326.
  cross-check: 1326.
```

---

***EDIT 1***

> The disconnect is, which two operations are the ones included with `ModularArithmetic<Integer>`...

So I had a chance to go though the source code and [add more missing documentation](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/caea6f1c593ec93abe38339c3757e637f546c616). Of particular interest is [`AbstractRing< T >` Class Template Reference](https://cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_abstract_ring.html), which `ModularArithmetic` inherits from. It confirms that multiply and exponentiation are the operations (and it gives rise to helpers, like `Square`).

What I am not clear about is why `ModularArithmetic` is providing `Add`, `Subtract` and friends but arriving at unexpected results. It could well be that its effectively accumulating the results and waiting to be reduced with a `Multiply` or `Exponentiate`, but I don't see any comments in the source code.

---

***EDIT 2***

The reason `ModularArithmetic` appears to produce incorrect results for `Add`, `Subtract` and friends is the class is meant to be fast for specific problems, and it does not perform a full reduction using the Euclidean extended algorithm. Rather, it performs *at most* one subtraction. That means the accumulated value `n` to be reduced by the modulus `p` must be in the range `[0, 2p)`.